# PHP extension "mcrypt" must be loaded

Tags: php, magento1.9.3, mcrypt

I'm trying to install **Magento 1.9.3** but got stuck on PHP extension **mcrypt** must be loaded.

I have two versions of PHP (5.6, and 7.1) both have mcrypt installed and running,
checked on both versions with

```
./php -m
```

mcrypt is in the list of running extensions, also added additionally in the

**/ect/php.ini extension=mcrypt.so**

I don't know what else to do to make it pass that installation screen.

Comment: have you restarted apache after this changes ????

Comment: For Refference  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26116530/php-extension-mcrypt-must-be-loaded

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18968792/php-extension-mcrypt-must-be-loaded

Answer (score 4):

I recommend to restart the web server.

Run php file with:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

and check whether there is a `mcrypt` extension, if no check path for right php.ini file.

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-mcrypt
sudo service apache2 graceful
```

Try above commands if it's still not working.

Comment: In windows how to do the above step?

Comment: worked for me. php5.6 on ubuntu 18.04. thanks

Answer (score 1):

IF you have access to SSH for your server install php5-mcrypt

```
$ sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
```

or

```
$ yum install php5-mcrypt
```

depends of your linux ditribution.